# SQL Server Table Synonyms with Indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, synonym

I have multiple databases on a single instance of SQL Server 2005.  I've created a synonym on one database to access a table on another database and when writing my queries, I'd like to utilize a specific index, however, when evaluating the execution plan, it doesn't appear to use it.  If I write the query to access the database explicitly, it works, but I can't seem to get it to work using a synonym.  For example:

```
select *
from testdb..testtable with (index(testindex))

|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([testdb].[dbo].[testtable].[id]))
     |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([testdb].[dbo].[testtable].[testindex]))
     |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([testdb].[dbo].[testtable].[PK_testtable]), SEEK:([testdb].[dbo].[testtable].[id]=[testdb].[dbo].[testtable].[id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
```

does not yield the same execution plan as

```
select *
from testdb_synonym with (index(testindex))

|--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([testdb].[dbo].[testtable].[PK_testtable]))
```

Is this a limitation with Synonyms or is there something specific I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Could you please post underlying plans for both queries? Just run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON GO SELECT …`

Comment: I've updated the description to include the execution plan...

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug that Microsoft have fixed:  see [MS KB 963684](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963684)

> In Microsoft SQL Server 2005, you
>   create a synonym for a table. You run
>   a query against the synonym. The query
>   uses the INDEX optimizer hint to force
>   an index. If you examine the execution
>   plan that is generated for the query,
>   you may find the execution plan does
>   not use the forced index.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the same thing and it seems that the query optimizer ignores that hint when done via a synonym.  The details are I did a select * against an arbitrary table with an index hint to use a non-clustered index.  Without the synonym, it does a bookmark lookup/nested loop join.  With it, it does a table scan.  Since there are no options on the create synonym syntax, I can only assume that the index hint is ignored.  No details in BOL as to why.  I would chalk it up as a "feature".

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case... It's been touted as an aliasing feature with part of the benefit of it to simplify the dot notation.  I can understand if it was going against a remote server, but if it's a local server, I was hoping that it would be smart enough to take advantage of the inherent benefits.

Answer (score 1):

`WITH INDEX` hints seems to be ignored for synonyms.

```
CREATE SYNONYM syn_master FOR master

SELECT  *
FROM    syn_master WITH (INDEX (wow_i_can_write_everything_here))
```

compiles and runs allright despite the fact I don't have an index named `wow_i_can_write_everything_here` in my schema.

Comment: No longer true for SQL Server 2008 R2.  BTW: you're creating a synonym to the master DB, I don't think that would work (select * from master??).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the hint in your case? MS recommendations is to avoid index hints if it is possible due to the fact that may invalidate a more optimized plan. Even if it is optimized today it may be inefficiens tomorrow due to data load etc.

I tried to use a synonym without the hint in SQL server 2008 and got the same execution plan with the synonym as with the fully qualified name (database.schema.table).

I even tried to use the synonym with an index hint and successfully forced a non clustered index seek (and a key lookup to get the rest of the data), and i get the same execution plan with fully qualified name.

Are your statisitics updated? Do you have a selective index or does SQL server think it is more efficient to use a table scan.