# SQL SYNONYM and performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, synonym

I have a requirement for some reporting and different environments, and the SQL `Synonym` would make a lot of sense with making our solution work.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

However, the operational support department doesn't like the idea, due to 'performace implications'. I can't see why there would be any performance degradation. But, has anyone had experience with SYNONYMs and medium sized databases (100gb) and performance issues?

Should I be worried, or have Microsoft covered this, and whether you use a SYNONYM, or the fully qualified [Database].[schema].[tablename] in a query - is there any difference - performance wise?

Comment: Your operational support department is confused. A synonym is just an alias (or you could say a pointer); not at all sure what performance implication there could possibly be, except that maybe it's transparent to devs that this two-part synonym actually references a table over a linked server connected by can and string... Or if you use explicit index hints (!) *and* are on an ancient unpatched version of SQL Server.

Comment: duplicate of [SQL Server - Synonyms Tips & Tricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796791/sql-server-synonyms-tips-tricks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good SO thread on synonyms.  Performance shouldn't be an issue on same server.  I'm not sure cross server.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796791/sql-server-synonyms-tips-tricks

Comment: In such a case, you should just mark this thread as a duplicate of the other, instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you use linked servers or cross-database queries you introduce potential and well documented performance issues.  For example, the query typically becomes a distributed query.  Also, the Optimizer has limited or no access to remote statistics so the query plan is unlikely to be 'optimal'.
Using a synonym just hides the complexity under an alias that usually looks like a local reference and tempts developers to do things across the linked server that they should not such as nested sub-queries and complex, multi-table joins.

That said, I am seriously considering synonyms but I will emphasize their special nature by a naming convention (e.g. syn_theTable) and coding rules :)